# What are the parallel (equivalent) tiles of FlipTile, IconicTyle, CycleTile from WP8 in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-phone-8, live-tile

What are the parallel (equivalent) tiles of FlipTile, IconicTyle, CycleTile from WP8 in Windows 8?
There are a lot in Windows 8 and they seem static.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

There are no direct parallels with the Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 tile templates.

While Windows Phone uses a "flip" to show multiple pieces of information on a single tile, Windows 8 uses a "peep" or slide animation to move between multiple tile faces. You should use whichever of the peek templates is most appropriate to the data you wish to display on the tile.

There is no direct equivalent of the WP8 IconicTileTemplate.
The nearest similar templates are `TileSquareBlock` or `TileWideBlockAndText0X` as these allow a large number to be displayed, but no icon.

The nearest thing Windows8 has to the CycleTileTemplate is `TileWideImageCollection` as that is the Win8 way of showing multiple images.

For Ref: [List of Win8 Tile templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761491.aspx)